# java.sql.SQLException: Column Index out of range, 2 > 1

Tags: java, sql, swing

I have a error message that I don't understand. The message is the next "java.sql.SQLException: Column Index out of range, 2 > 1" 
I ask me if my problem comes from my request sql ?

```
String req = "Select A.CodeA from album A, collabo C where A.CodeA = C.CodeA order by 1 ";
        ResultSet resu = ConnexionMySQL.getInstance().selectQuery (req);
        try {
            while (resu.next())
            {  
                myList.add (new Appareil(resu.getString(1), 
                             new Album (resu.getString(2))));

             }
        }
```

Or perhaps in my file TableModel Appareil ?I have a column "Identification" only I don't understand why it doesn't works ?

```
private String[] columnNames = {"Identification"};
    private ArrayList <Appareil> myList;

    public TableModelAppareils (ArrayList myList)
    {
        this.myList = myList;
    }

    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columnNames.length;
    }

    public int getRowCount() {
        //System.out.println("row count : " + myList.size());
        return myList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int col) {
        return columnNames[col];
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
        Appareil myApp = myList.get(row);
        switch (col)
        {
            case 0 :    return myApp.getAppAlb().getCodeA();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Class getColumnClass(int c) {
        switch (c)
        {
            case 0 :    return String.class;

        }
        return null;
    }

    public void setMyList (ArrayList myList)
    {
        this.myList = myList;
        this.fireTableDataChanged();
    }

    public ArrayList <Appareil> getMyList ()
    {
        return myList;
    }

    public Appareil getMyList (int index)
    {
        return myList.get(index);
    }
```

Thank you a lot

Comment: You only have one column in your result set (A.codeA), and you are coding resu.getString(2)

Comment: I must do an INNER JOIN ? Because I have 2 tables...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are accessing a second column from `ResultSet` using `resu.getString(2)` in your code however you're just selecting one column `A.codeA` in your select query

Comment: So, my problem is my request sql ?

Comment: No, your request SQL query which select only "one" column is absolutely fine, but the code you've written is trying to access a second column from the query result using `resu.getString(2)` which isn't present, That is where things are going wrong

Comment: I am obliged, to have getString(2) to recuperate the item from my foreign key, I don't understand how to do for now... ;-(

Comment: Do you have the same value in your foreign key as well?

Comment: my problem is resolve, it was in my class Album the problem; thank you a lot for your help